# See real telemetry values second to second on iot central

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-central

I have used iot central of microsoft azure for two days but I haven't managed to graph the data that arrives second to second without an aggregate function (Average, minimum, maximum, sum, count), when I plot the data in the graphic, It is always shown as a aggregate function for example: The device send data every second but in the graphic one point can be from 09:39:03 to 09:39:16 and in this case it shows me the value of the average in this range of time

[image: average value]

The problem is that I need to see the data second to second to identify something irregular in the data, Is there a way to achieve it? The only way I have found is doing zoom in the data but I would have to use the zoom at each time interval to look for an irregularity in the data

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to view the data without applying aggregation on it. It would be great if you can log this as a feature request at http://aka.ms/iotcuservoice.

Comment: Over 4 years on, is there a solution to this problem ? I can't see any way of displaying or plotting actual/current/live values in IOT Central. Because I'm logging values that "count things", the average, sum, min or max are completely useless to the user.